# Configuration of OpenCV 2.3 of Python in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, opencv, pydev

Hi I'm just starting to use python and OpenCV, my IDE is eclipse.

Now I have installed NumPy and SciPy and OpenCV 2.3 and Python 2.7

and I think I configure all the path and interpreter options (may be may not),

here comes the problem:

[image: this is the screen shot of my IDE, all the cv-related are marked wrong in the editor but actually when I run it, it turns out to be fine]

so my question is how to make it work fine as in other languages as Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Eclipse go to

**`Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter=> [Forced Builtins]`**(tab)

Add cv (or cv2) and apply - all will be fine.

Comment: I added cv2 (not cv [for my version]) and now all is working fine

Comment: An eclipse restart was required, but now It's working fine - thanks.

Comment: Do I need to intall cv before adding? I am a total newbie please help. @Coderzelf

Comment: Yes - If you're going to use OpenCV, it'd probably be a good idea to install it first. 